# Fracking Cost per Barrel of Oil

Tags: data-request, api, finance, economics

I am looking for a historic and on-going source for fracking cost per barrel of oil.  Ideally for the USA with regional and/or State values.  However, larger sources are welcome.

Any ideas?

Comment: Per barrel of.....

Comment: @Ifyoudonotknow-justGIS Oil

Comment: Relevant: http://economics.stackexchange.com/a/1788/240

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:

In 2014/2015, Maybe **$48/BOE** (Barrel of Oil Equivalent). The $48 is the sum of the negative items in the slide below. This unit cost is currently unprofitable.

However, there is oil-fracking, and there is gas fracking. Gas-fracking is more profitable.

Long answer:

See this [2015 presentation](https://www.greenlightcapital.com/926698.pdf) from star hedge-fund manager [David Einhorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Einhorn_(hedge_fund_manager)).

On slide 36-38, he says:

> How much does it cost for [oil fracking company] Pioneer to create a
> developed reserve? This chart looks at Pioneer cumulatively over the
> past 9 years.  It has grown its developed reserves by about 30 million
> BOE and taken about 470 million out of the ground.  So, it has
> developed about 500 million BOE.   Capex net of asset sales during
> that same period has been $14 billion, meaning reserves have cost $28
> per BOE to develop.
>
> [...]
>
> On the $36 of revenues per BOE, Pioneer spends about $14 on field
> operating expenses and another $6 on corporate expenses. Subtract the
> historical $28 of Capex, and Pioneer loses $12 for every BOE it
> develops.

[image]

And see slide 66: In the long run, Schlumberger Corp. estimates a "Capex" value of **$80/BBL** unlike Pioneer  which has $28/BOE.

You can find much more detailed data (for this Pioneer company), and more fundamentals about the industry in the 92-page-PDF of the conference presentation I've linked to.

In any case, I think the question is asked in a too general way, and a bit naive. It's like "which type of car has the best bang for the buck"?. It depends.

Comment: This is a good resource. (+1). However, it only looks at one company. I'm seeking an industry aggregate average/median cost as is available for offshore drilling or onshore drilling.

Comment: Slide 65 (the Goldman Sachs -data) shows that Pioneer is pretty representative for the industry.

Answer (score -2):

The data is available here -:

https://www.datazar.com/file/fc2291b01-6d5c-48ac-a260-b8e8260dddad

P.S- I work for datzar, an open source data library, where people can discover, share and work with data.

Comment: Somehow I doubt the cost of a barrel fracked of oil is $2.36.  Also, fracking is a very new method of extraction so I doubt there would be cost all the way back to 1918.

Comment: The original source of the data has been mentioned there :) !

Comment: The source is for gasoline prices per gallon.  The question asks for fracking cost per barrel of oil. They are very very far from being the same thing.

Comment: The link is now dead.